# macOS and Xamarin IDE doesn't see my iPad

Tags: xamarin, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I’ve installed MacOX X Sierra on VMWare. 
 All right, but OS does not detect any iOS device connected via USB cable. 
I spent two days on solving this problem(
 
Any ideas?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Xamarin IDE doesn't see your iPad or macOS doesn't see it. Title says one thing, question another...

Comment: macOS and Xamarin IDE

Comment: That's strange, but it is a VMWare issue then. If it was just Xamarin I had an idea...

Comment: Launch iTunes first, to see if it can see your iPad.

Comment: Windows sees my iPad, VMWare sees my iPad, but iTunes doesn't iPad=(    Here is a screenshot https://ibb.co/hRWJ1Q